# message.channel.send(lvlEmbed).then(msg => {msg.delete(1000)}); not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I use

```
message.channel.send(lvlEmbed).then(msg => {msg.delete(1000)});
```

it doesn't work. It only works if i put no time. I'm not sure what's going on. It worked once then never worked! What's wrong?

Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

let xp = require("../xp.json");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (!xp[message.author.id]) {
        xp[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level: 1
        };
    }
    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtLvlXp = curlvl * 300;
    let difference = nxtLvlXp - curxp;

    let lvlEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setColor("#e000f4")
        .addField("Level", curlvl, true)
        .addField("XP", curxp, true)
        .setFooter(`${difference} XP til level up`, message.author.displayAvatarURL);

    message.channel.send(lvlEmbed).then(msg => { msg.delete(5000) });


}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "level"
}
```

Comment: Try catching аn error `message.channel.send(lvlEmbed).then(msg => { msg.delete(5000); }).catch(err => { console.error(err); });` What printed in the console?

Comment: i dont get an error in the console

Comment: By _it doesn't work_ you mean that it doesn't send the message at all or only that it doesn't delete it? Have you tried using longer times: if your internet is slow and you delete the message after only 1 second you could not even see it.

Comment: Does it work everytime you specify no parameter to the delete function?

Comment: Hello i figured out the reason Using "nodemon" everytime it randomized it restarted the bot making it unable to delete the message

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying that it works if you're not inputting any time to the delete function, temporarily you could use the setTimeout to get the job done.

```
let p = function(msg){
   msg.delete();
}
message.channel.send(lvlEmbed).then(msg => { setTimeout(p,5000,msg); });
```